# R is a ring $\mathbf{a}$ is an ideal... give the image of the pullback of the natural projection on spectrum of R/a

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

$R$ is a ring. $\mathbf{a}$ an ideal. If $\pi$ is the natural projection $R \mapsto R/\mathbf{a} $, and the map $\pi^*:\mathrm{Spec}(R / \mathbf{a}) \mapsto \mathrm{Spec}(R)$, give the image of $\pi^*( R/\mathbf{a})$.
($\pi^*$ is the pullback I guess but this is new to me.)

This is what I have so far: 
Let $\mathbf{a} \subset M$, where $M$ is a maxmimal ideal containing $\mathbf{a}$.

$\mathrm{Spec}(R/\mathbf{a})= \{n + \mathbf{a} : n \in M\ \text{ and } n + \mathbf{a} \text{ is a prime ideal of } R/\mathbf{a} \}$

This is the same as the set:

$\{\pi(n) | n \in M, \pi(n) \text{ prime ideal of } R/\mathbf{a}\}$

If $\pi(n)$ is a prime ideal then, for for some ...

And here I want to use some element in $\pi(n)$ that is a product, and then show the pull back is...

help.  please.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\mathfrak{p}\in \mathrm{Spec}(R/\mathfrak{a})$ the map $\pi^{*}$ is as follows $\pi^{*}(\mathfrak{p})=\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$, the inverse image of the prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ under $\pi$.

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formulated question.  It was a long day. I was tired.  Anyway, I dug up a useful thing I didn't know applied.  But, the 1-1 correspondence between the ideals of R that contain $\mathbf{a}$ and the ideals of $\R/\mathbf{a}$ can be taken to be a 1-1 correspondence between primes of $R/\mathbf{a}$ and the primes of $R$ that contain $\mathbf{a}$. So: 

The image $\pi^*[Spec(R/\mathbf{a})]$ is the set of all primes of $R$ that contain $\mathbf{a}$.  

Is there more to it than that? Am I over simplifying?

Comment: Yes, $\pi^{*}$ as defined here is the map from primes of $R/\mathfrak{a}$ to primes of $R$ containing $\mathfrak{a}$ that is used in the proof of that fact.

Comment: Sorry,  to clarify... yes, I've over simplified or that is all there is to that?

Comment: My comment is pretty much all there is to finding the image of $Spec(R/\mathfrak{a})$ under $\pi^{*}$.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate the help.